# saving data in mysql but cant

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**when i place a static value it works but when i use $a it print correct values but did't save the value in database**

```
<?php

    $conn_error='Could not Connect';
    $mysql_host='localhost';
    $mysql_user='root';
    $mysql_pass='';
    $mysql_db='db_ZS';

    $con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $a=$_POST['txtEn'];
    echo $a;

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tlb1 (AR,EN) values ($a,$a)");

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Better off using PDO - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php as it stands your query is SQL inject vector and it would be trivial to wipe out your database without trying to hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your variable holds a string value, you need to use `'` quotes

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tlb1 (AR,EN) values ('$a','$a')");
```

Also make sure you atleast sanitize your data using `mysqli_real_escape_string` before you post anything to the database..

And also make sure your column datatype is `varchar` or `text` if it's a string as `int`, `bigint` columns doesn't store text values

> Tip: Always use `echo mysqli_error($connection);` which will help you debug your queries

Comment: thasnkx it works
but it did't save unicode text
do u ny idea

Comment: @SHAKEELHUSSAIN You need to use `utf8_*` character set for your tables

Comment: how could display  this "ب"

echo "ب";// did't work